# Facebook Graph api /me/home : Not reliable

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

We are encountering an issue during the current Hackathon in my company. We access to our newsfeed through the FQL.

When we try to access to some old (but not so much!) informations, we are confronted to a problem: sometimes we have some datas returned, sometimes not.

That's a big deal for us cause it makes our project non reliable.

Example:
`fql?q=select source_id, message, attachment, created_time from stream where filter_key="nf" AND created_time < 1323648660`

Sometimes returns:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Sometimes returns a list a 25 datas as expected.

Look like a wrong cache management?

Is this an open bug for FB ? It's kind of critical.

Hope you will be able to help me,

Regards,

François JAGUELIN

Answer (score 0):

Limit the source_id to one user, for example:

```
fql?q=select source_id, message, attachment, created_time from stream where filter_key="nf" AND created_time < 1323648660 AND source_id = XXXX
```

When you don't limit the source_id to one user, the time you query over is greatly reduced.  If you need to query over multiple source_id's, pack single source_id queries into a multiquery.

From FbDevWiki...

*The stream table is really two concepts built into one table. If you specify a filter_key and/or multiple users, the results will behave like the stream in Facebook's home page. If only one user is specified, and no filter_key is specified, the table will assume that you want a profile-like view, and all that implies.
Those behaviors differ significantly. For example, the homepage-like view only aggregates data over the last few days. The profile-like view gets much older data from our databases.*